# UITextfield doesn't show keyboard after dismiss from presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, ios6

I am working with an app which required to open "MPMoviePlayerViewController" when clicked on a video file.

There is a tabbarController into our app which has four Navigation controllers for four tabs.

My app only support portrait orientation, but video should support both landscape & portrait orientations. So, I make Subclass of  "MPMoviePlayerViewController".

Code of that class..

```
@interface MyMovieViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController
@end

@implementation MyMovieViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:NO];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

In First tab, I show Gallery. There is a code to open video file.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));
            MPMoviePlayerViewController * vc = [[MyMovieViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[[[elcAsset asset] valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] valueForKey:[[[[elcAsset asset] valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]]];
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            // Remove the movie player view controller from the "playback did finish" notification observers
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:vc
                                                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                          object:vc.moviePlayer];

            // Register this class as an observer instead
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             addObserver: self
             selector: @selector(doneButtonClick:)
             name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
             object: vc.moviePlayer];

            [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:vc];
            [vc.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
            [vc.moviePlayer play];
```

Video is working file. It also support both orientations. but when I switch to another tab, then no textfield show keyboard when clicked on it.

Please help. Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue.
Actually, MPMoviePlayerViewController support both orientations and my app support only portrait. When i dismiss MPMoviePlayerViewController,then parentview of it think that it is Landscape mode. 
So, it display landscape keyboard, which's CGPoint is lower than screen. Thats why I am not able to see keyboard.

I have make write following code into my CustomNavigationController.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return [self.visibleViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

Now, it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to dismiss Your MoviePlayer..

Use this notification that calls when your video is over

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:self.theMoviePlayer];
```

and write method of it.

```
-(void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this delegate method,

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

  [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];

  return YES;

}

If this does not work, try to find out what is called after dismissing the view and then insert following code... This will definitely work.

[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];